# Xamarin Forms проблема с ContextCompat

Tags: android, xamarin

В документации Майкрософт я прочитал, что для проверки того, предоставлено ли конкретное разрешение используется метод ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission, который в библиотеке Xamarin.Android.Support.v4. Но этот пакет я могу установить только в проект Название.Android. Если я хочу установить его в сам проект, где пишу код, то получаю ошибку Пакет Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0.3 несовместим с netstandard2.0, и требует одну из версий monoandroid.

Не понимаю, как мне проверять разрешения, если я не могу установить этот пакет в проект.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 платформозависимый. Ваша сборка, где пишется основной код, скорее всего, платформонезависимая. droid сборка может референсить Вашу основную, но не наоборот. пишете интерфейс в сборке с основным кодом или в отдельной платформонезависимой. в дроид сборке Вы реализуете интерфейс и регистрируете эту функцию или свой объект в Вашем коде. основной код вызывает CheckSelfPermission через интерфейс. профит.